# Unable to get JSON keys in an array using Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to retrieve all the keys off a query result into an array. Should be a super easy thing to do but somehow am not able to. Here's the snippet:

```
fromMongoDB = parent.posts[0]
returnedkeys = Object.keys(fromMongoDB);
console.log(fromMongoDB);
console.log('-----------------------------');
console.log(returnedkeys);
```

The data I'm receiving into `fromMongoDB` is an object with two key-value pairs:

```
{
   id: <some ID>,
   title: <some title>
}
```

Using `Object.keys()`, I intend to get an array of the two keys:

```
[
  id, title
]
```

But this is what I'm getting instead:

```
{ id: '5ba1f3e7cc546723422e62a4', title: 'A Title!' }
-----------------------------
[ '__parentArray',
  '__parent',
  '__index',
  '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '_doc',
  '$init' ]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is `fromMongoDB` not a JSON object?

Comment: I got it working with a very simple tweak:

    ```const returnedkeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fromMongoDB._doc)```

Although it worked, I still find it a bit of an obscure solution as one would still expect `Object.keys()` to expose all keys in the object which it didn't in my case. Hence, even though my problem stands resolved, I'm not posting this as an answer because the question still remains: why should `Object.keys(fromMongoDB._doc)` work while `Object.keys(fromMongoDB)` not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [lean()](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.11-lean-virtuals) function instead.
Append .lean() to your query and then use Object.keys() to get an array of keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.4.4** and above

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "keys": {
      "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "keys": "$keys.k" }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fromMongoDB);
```

Comment: Still returns:

```[ '__parentArray',
  '__parent',
  '__index',
  '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '_doc',
  '$init' ]```